# Sharing checked out codebase between multiple Maven jobs

Tags: maven, jenkins

For some legacy reasons that are much overdue to be refactored, one of the sub projects in our build hierarchy is subject to two separate `Maven` builds, each with its own WAR file. Essentially, and I shouldn't have to go in detail germane to this matter, that project ought to be split into two projects each having its own WAR but is not yet (PMs won't allocate time to do it) so we work around by running two separate builds the specificity of each being represented by their own POM profile.

`mvn clean verify -P foo` makes foo.war out of the same project that `mvn clean verify -P bar` makes bar.war.

I am working on `CI` and I need to `Jenkins`-ize the project. I installed the [`Maven plugin`](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Maven+Project+Plugin) but the source code management section allows that the local code base be checked out in a directory relative to the job's workspace root AND that only one mvn build is allowed per job. That leaves me with the option of having two separate jobs, each checking out its own local codebase snapshot, which is an overkill IMO.

If there was a way to have the `foo` job check out in a directory not internal to its workspace that is accessible also to `bar`, which would not be using SCM but assume the presence of the source code by different means (in this case by job foo or manually), I could run my second build out of the same physically checked out source code and not have to do it all over again. That is just one way that comes to mind in addition to maybe somehow enabling the one Jenkins job to run more than one build but I think that's not an option.

I am looking for ideas how to solve this problem within the Maven Jenkins plugin and not resorting to agnosticize my job as Jenkins freestyle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an upstream job which checks out the src from SVN. This job triggers the two different mvn downstream jobs - to this jobs you pass the workspace of the parent job as parameter. In the substream job you have to use this parameter as the custom workspace.

In jenkins you can specify the workspace for a job (its somewhere in the advanced options) above the SCM options when I am not fully wrong - have currently no Jenkins instance to check this.

**EDIT**:
The custom workspace option is in the general section in the advanced options below "Restrict where this project can be run" and is called "Use custom workspace".
If this does not work for you there is a plugin called "shared workspace" available but actually this should not required in your case.

Comment: so the downstream jobs would not be using SCM -- but i cannot find the advanced option you are referring to where I specify the workspace (source code location) in case i am using existing and not checking out

Comment: I think I found it -- it's under the `Build` section

Comment: is there any way the SCM plugin can check the codebase out in a directory location outside the Jenkins workspace ?

Comment: Exactly with this custom workspace. You can give Jenkins actually an arbitrary path.